# Rails Rspec - Run only single test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I am learning RSpec. I want to just run the rspec on a single file. I accomplishes it through

```
cd to/my/project
```

and

```
rspec ./spec/parent/child/spec.rb
```

But after I gave this command

```
rspec --order rand:seed
```

my rspec is running all test from the first. How do I undo this command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to run a single test:

```
rspec ./spec/parent/child/spec.rb:line_number_of_your_test
```

`line_number_of_your_test` can be any number spanning the test if your `it` block is a multi-line block.

Update: Removed 'rand:seed' part.

Comment: It is still running from the first (all tests).

Comment: can you try without specifying `--order rand:seed`?

Comment: Also, here https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/order i don't see any such option as `rand:seed` unless by `seed`, you mean a seed number.

Comment: This should also be helpful: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/command-line/line-number-appended-to-file-path

Comment: @JagdeepSingh why `rand:seed`if you are going to run just one test?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to run

```
rspec your_file.rb:number_of_line
```

So if your file's name is `login.rb` and it looks like

```
1 describe "test something" do
2  it "signup" do
3   ...
4  end
5  it "signin" do
6   ...
7  end
8 end
```

and you want to run just `"signin"` test, you need to run

```
rspec login.rb:5
```